# How to add random delay spikes to this?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I finally got my progress bar the way I want, is there a way to make it have delay spikes? like its actually loading data, for now this is just for looks on my website but I would like it to look authentic. heres the code. the max delay I would need and want is 500 milliseconds.

```
<html><head>
    <style>
        #adLinkb,
#adLinkb2 {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="adLinkb" style="border: 1px solid black;width:212;background-color:black;border-color:white"></div>
    <br>
<div id="adLinkb2" style="border: 1px solid black;width:212;background-color:black;border-color:white"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function buildBar(id, callback) {
  var currentAdb = 0;
  var imgCtb = 70;

  function cycleb() {
    var output = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < imgCtb; i++) {
      output += i > currentAdb ? '&nbsp;' : '/';
    }
    output += '';
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = output;
    ++currentAdb;
    if (currentAdb == imgCtb) {
      window.clearInterval(myInterval);
      if (typeof callback == 'function') {
        callback();
      }
    }
  }
  var myInterval = window.setInterval(cycleb, 100);
}

function callback1() {
  buildBar('adLinkb2', callback2);
}

function callback2() {
  //window.location... stuff here
  alert('redirect should go here');
}

buildBar('adLinkb', callback1);
    </script>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `setInterval` with a `setTimeout` and re-schedule with a random timeout

`window.setTimeout(cycleb,10+Math.random()*300);`

the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/martijn/qqf90r3f/

alternative spike:

```
if(Math.random()>0.9)
         {
             // 10% change on a spike
                window.setTimeout(cycleb,10+Math.random()*1000);
         }
         else{
             window.setTimeout(cycleb,10+Math.random()*10);
         }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/martijn/qqf90r3f/1/

Comment: sidenote, you are 'fooling' the user here by showing progress "simulation'. You probably don't know how long the request is going to take, or providing a real progress system is not feasible. Consider using a  Indeterminate progress indicator. See : http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/21727/indeterminate-progress-indicator-styles

Comment: Thanks, but Im seeing no change is there a way to make it slower and faster rate of spikes showing?